# It is possible to add esxi5.5 host into vcenter6.5?

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere, vcenter, esxi5.5

The purpose is that we have vCenter6.5 and we also have some of the esxi5.5 hosts and we want to migrate it to vCenter6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the VMware Interoperability Matrices it is supported. You should be able to add it.
https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/sim/interop_matrix.php#interop&2=3364&1=795,620
As for the ESXi upgrade, you can follow the process described here. https://vmiss.net/2016/12/20/how-to-upgrade-esxi-using-vsphere-update-manager-6-5-on-the-vcenter-server-appliance/
I would recommend you to upgrade to vCenter 6.7 and ESXi 6.7. It will supported till 2022. And has nice features.
https://www.vmwareblog.org/whats-new-vmware-vsphere-6-7-update-1-lets-look-hood/